# mapreduce Job() threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.toString()

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

I'm running a Spark Streaming program that uses a mapreduce Job to write files in AvroParquet format. The program works properly when executed on the cluster but fails in local.

The code

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job
val job = Job.getInstance()
```

throws the following exception:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.toString()
```

Here is the code used to submit the spark streaming job:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(false)
                .setMaster("local[2]")
                .setAppName("test");
    SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
    MyClass job = new MyClass();
    job.run();

    class MyClass(){
    protected def run(): Unit ={

        val ssc: StreamingContext = createStreamingContext(parameters)
        // here there is something like 
        // stream.map(func1).reduceBykey(func2).foreachRDD(rdd => {val job = Job.getInstance()})
        ssc.start()
    }
```

Comment: Are you submitting the job locally with spark-submit too?

Comment: No, I've edited the question to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this is a non-blocking exception.
I could see the exception in Debug mode but the program can execute correctly till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it happens because it tries to call toString on your job before it is submitted.

Instead of manually creating the Job instance, try submitting it with spark-submit --class MyClass --master local[2] /path/to/yourjar.jar ([Submitting spark applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html))

Your code could look something like this:

```
object MyClass {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={
    val conf = new SparkConf(false)
            .setMaster("local[2]")
            .setAppName("test");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf);

    // do what you need
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of idea, it will process toString automatically. You need to set it in debugger in idea and remove the check for automatic processing of header string. It should be "builder, exception, deployer" in this.

Comment: I do not understand above use of `idea`: do you intend [IDE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)? I see no indication *IntelliJ IDEA* belongs into the picture.

Comment: “https://www.facebook.com/jingqing.peng.16” is my Facebook 's link! We can detail show.